# How to insert new item to channel in xml file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I want modify an existing xml file to insert new element inside the Channel using vb code 
my xml file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<channel>
<title>Latest News from Science Magazine</title>
<link>http://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news_current.xml</link>
<description>Editable in modal at Format : RSS Feed | Settings : RSS Description</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 25 Jul 2018 09:10:28 -0400</pubDate

<item>
  <title><![CDATA[this is title]]></title>
  <link>http://karary-001-site1.htempurl.com</link>
  <pubDate>2018/07/26 06:29</pubDate>
  <description><![CDATA[this id desc]]></description>
  <media.thumbnail url="http://karary.com" height="266" width="127" />
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

this is my code :

```
Dim root = New XElement("item")
    Dim title = New XElement("title", New XCData(TextBox3.Text))
    Dim link = New XElement("link", TextBox6.Text)
    Dim pubDate = New XElement("pubDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy/MM/dd HH:mm"))
    Dim description = New XElement("description", New XCData(TextBox5.Text))
    Dim thumbnail = New XElement("media.thumbnail",
                                  New XAttribute("url", "http://karary-001-site1.htempurl.com/files/" + attac1 + "?itok=YdFLolAU"),
                                  New XAttribute("height", 266),
                                  New XAttribute("width", 127))
    root.Add(title, link, pubDate, description, thumbnail)
    document.Root.Add(root)
    document.Save(FilePath)
```

my code add new items after channel and rss tag end !!

Comment: that's probably because you added it to the root? I imagine you need to locate the channel element within the document and add it to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently adding it to the document's root element, which in this case is `<rss />`. Instead you want to add it to the root element's first element:

```
document.Root.Elements.First().Add(root)
```

Comment: still add new items after channel and rss tag end !!

Comment: @MichaelJoseph - Then the XML you are providing us is not the same as the XML that you're using. Take a look at this example https://dotnetfiddle.net/tWTR8o